# How to pass UserID or UserName into another page in asp.net membership feature using Query String?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have used asp.net membership feature in my project. My code in 'manage-users.aspx' is;

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridUserAccounts" SkinID="gridviewSkin" PageSize="5">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="User Name" DataField="UserName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" DataField="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Login Date" SortExpression="LastLoginDate" DataField="LastLoginDate" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Activity Date" SortExpression="LastActivityDate" DataField="LastActivityDate" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "manage-user-detail.aspx?UserID=" %>' ID="linkNavigate" Text="View Detail" />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

my code behind for this grid view is this;

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    gridUserAccounts.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    gridUserAccounts.DataBind();
}
```

Now, my question is "How do pass the selected userID into another page i-e 'manage-user-detail.aspx' page using querystring in this 'item template' (in NavigateUrl property).

```
<asp:TemplateField>                          
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "manage-user-detail.aspx?UserID=" %>'   ID="linkNavigate" Text="View Detail" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And "How do i show the the user details (catch querystring first and then) and show result in fromview in 'manage-user-detail.aspx' page.
Any help will be apreciatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("manage-user-detail.aspx?UserID={0}",Eval("UserID")) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alway access the username this way:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

**UPDATE**
If you want the data for a specific user you will need to retrieve the `MembershipUser` instance by username:

```
var userName = "someUserName";
var membershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(userName);
```

Here are the available infos on the `MembershipUser` class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx

Comment: does this give the online user identity. becuase i want to show the user detail when i click on a particular hyperlink in gridview. In short, i don't wan to show the online user but i want to show the detail of selected user (in gridview)

Comment: Yes, if a user is logged in this will return it's username, if he is not logged in the Identity is null and it would raise an exception

Comment: but i need selected user identity. Becuase i have to do all these operations in admin page.

Comment: just updated the answer to reflect the additional info you just provided

Comment: this does workout NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("manage-user-detail.aspx?UserID={0}",Eval("UserID")) %>'. Thanks for your quick reply